# Numbers of weekdays in a date range in TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, math

This is harder than it looks. I need a function that calculates the numbers of a given weekday in a date range. I don't want any loops or recursive SQL. There are millions of examples doing just that. I need a fast function for calculation.

Input of the function will be weekday, fromdata, todate

```
-- counting fridays
set datefirst 1
SELECT dbo.f_countweekdays(5, '2011-07-01', '2011-07-31'),
dbo.f_countweekdays(5, '2011-07-08', '2011-07-15'),
dbo.f_countweekdays(5, '2011-07-09', '2011-07-15'),
dbo.f_countweekdays(5, '2011-07-09', '2011-07-14')
```

Expected result:

```
5, 2, 1, 0
```

Comment: Sorry about the close vote. Misread the question.

Comment: My own version works now, is it wrong to post it as an answer or should I add it as part of the question ? It is very different from the current answers.

Comment: You can post it as an answer and I think you should be able to accept your own answer as well. I think there is a time limit before you can accept it.

Comment: Mikael. Thx. I don't think people should be allowed to choose their own answers. That would lead to abuse. Also in this case I had alot longer to think about it than you had. I am not qualified to estimate which function is fastest. Which in this case will be the function I will use. Any good surgestion of how to compare them ?

Comment: Tried to do a performance test using a numbers table and executing the function 100000 times. Took 10 seconds and the difference between our two versions was 60 ms. Not sure the test was any good :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Mikael Eriksson has got a wonderful idea, but his implementation seems a bit overcomplicated.

Here's what I've come up with (and I'd like to stress that **it is based on the [solution by @Mikael](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704905/numbers-of-weekdays-in-a-date-range-in-tsql/6705489#6705489)**, to whom the main credit should go):

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.f_countweekdays (@Dow int, @StartDate datetime, @EndDate datetime)
RETURNS int
AS BEGIN
  RETURN (
    SELECT
      DATEDIFF(wk, @StartDate, @EndDate)
      - CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, @StartDate) > @Dow THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      - CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, @EndDate)   < @Dow THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      + 1
  )
END
```

---

**UPDATE**

As Mikael has correctly noted in his answer's comment thread, in order for the above solution to work correctly the DATEFIRST setting must be set to `7` (Sunday). Although I couldn't find this documented, a quick test revealed that `DATEDIFF(wk)` disregards the actual DATEFIRST setting and indeed returns the difference in weeks as if DATEFIRST was always set to 7. At the same time `DATEPART(dw)` does respect `DATEFIRST`, so with DATEFIRST set to a value other than 7 the two functions return mutually inconsistent results.

Therefore, the above script must be amended in order to account for different values of the DATEFIRST setting when calculating `DATEDIFF(wk)`. Happily, the fix doesn't seem to have made the solution *much more* complicated than before, in my opinion. Judge for yourself, though:

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.f_countweekdays (@Dow int, @StartDate datetime, @EndDate datetime)
RETURNS int
AS BEGIN
  RETURN (
    SELECT
      DATEDIFF(wk, DATEADD(DAY, -@@DATEFIRST, @StartDate),
                   DATEADD(DAY, -@@DATEFIRST, @EndDate))
      - CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, @StartDate) > @Dow THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      - CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, @EndDate)   < @Dow THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      + 1
  )
END
```

<sup>**Edited:** both `-@@DATEFIRST % 7` entries have been simplified to just `-@@DATEFIRST`, as someone suggested [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/8cc3493a-7ae5-4759-ab2a-e7683165320b/).</sup>

Comment: Sorry been away from the internet, + 1 from me as well. Very nice

Answer (score 5):

```
create function dbo.f_countweekdays
(
  @DOW int, 
  @StartDate datetime, 
  @EndDate datetime
) 
returns int
begin
  return
  ( select datediff(wk, T2.St, T2.En) -
           case when T1.SDOW > @DOW then 1 else 0 end -
           case when T1.EDOW < @DOW then 1 else 0 end
    from (select datepart(dw, @StartDate),
                 datepart(dw, @EndDate)) as T1(SDOW, EDOW)
      cross apply (select dateadd(d, - T1.SDOW, @StartDate),
                          dateadd(d, 7 - T1.EDOW, @EndDate)) as T2(St, En))
end
```

Comment: +1 this works well. Very fancy. I had a more primitive approch myself when i tried to solve it.

Comment: I like the approach very much, but I think you somewhat overdid it. Please have a look at my solution.

Comment: @Andriy - I agree. It pretty much shows how I think. I did not take time to clean it up. However, our versions does not do the same thing. Your version requires `set datefirst 7` and my requires `set datefirst 1`. Test `dbo.f_countweekdays(5, '2011-07-11', '2011-07-17')`

Comment: You are right, and thank you very much for pointing that out! I don't remember having come across that peculiarity of DATEDIFF which I'm talking about of in my updated answer. It's very good to know this in advance.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative approach is the good old-fashioned data warehouse time dimension, where you have a table with all potential dates in it, along with any useful information you want to filter/count by:

```
Key       ActualDate  DayName   IsWeekday  DayNumberInYear  FinancialQuarter
20110101  1 Jan 2011  Saturday  0          1                2011 Q1
20110102  2 Jan 2011  Sunday    0          2                2011 Q1
20110103  3 Jan 2011  Monday    1          3                2011 Q1
```

Then just join to that table and filter, e.g.

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) 
FROM 
  date_dimension
WHERE
  ActualDate BETWEEN '1 Jan 2011' AND '3 Jan 2011' AND
  IsWeekday = 1
```

If you do date analysis a lot over a *known range of dates*, this can really speed up and simplify your queries. Whether you know your possible date ranges in advance is the limiting factor on whether this is helpful, really, but it's a useful trick to know about.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This seems like alot of work for 1 little function.

Comment: It is a lot of work for one little function. It gets more useful the more you want to do arbitrary things with dates, though, so I figured I'd mention it.

Comment: It is very little work and it is simple. After reading the other solutions here, and the solution that referred me here, I couldn't decide which of them to use because of the level of debate, the talk about the DATEFIRST setting, and the level of expertise required to understand them. So I went for something I understood.