# Finding specific days between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help to find out how many Fridays there are between two specific dates. I have found and read through the post concerning;
[Work days between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252519/count-work-days-between-two-dates) - but I'm not able to crack how to count specific days between two dates. I need a more reliable solution than just dividing it by 7.

Thanks!

Comment: You should tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: You should also post the failing code.

Comment: And also define “a more reliable solution than just dividing it by 7”. As long as a week has seven days, that number is going to come into play in one way or another.

Comment: @CBroe, an 8 day period can contain 1 or 2 Fridays.

Comment: @jarlh that could be "one way" or the "other way" CBore is talking about.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry, I have added this. Thanks for your reply

Comment: @Ejaz I have only been trying around with the code from the link I posted, so I don't have any code to post at this moment sorry.

Comment: Would following method work? `if first day of interval is friday, then, number_of_fridays = 1 ; number_of_fridays += integer value of (number of days in interval % 7);`?... or gives some direction?

Comment: @jarlh: Yes, of course. What day of week the start or end date (depending which side you start) actually is, has to be taken into account of course.

Comment: @DavidG Thanks, thats exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
declare @startDate date;
declare @endDate date;

select @startDate = '2017-02-01';
select @endDate = '2017-02-10';

with dateBetween as
(
  select dt = dateadd(dd, 1, @startDate)
  where dateadd(dd, 1, @startDate) < @endDate
  union all
  select dateadd(dd, 1, dt)
  from dateBetween
  where dateadd(dd,1, dt) < @endDate
)

select DATENAME(dw,dt) As [Dayname],dt as [Date]
from dateBetween where DATENAME(dw,dt) ='Friday'
```

Comment: Thanks a million Singh, perfect!

Comment: I added [option (maxrecursion 0)] at the end to remove the maximum recursion error message.

Comment: try option (maxrecursion 365)

Comment: My startDate and endDate are 14 years apart, so that won't work.

Comment: try Different CTE for each year and save in Temp Or Dynamic table then finally use (Temp Or Dynamic table) For insert

Comment: This is an awful solution, you only need some basic maths, as per the duplicate...

Comment: @DavidG save dates in Dynamic  table also so how can retrive duplicate data, can you suggest another solutions

Comment: Yes, the [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7563069/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-tuesdays-between-two-dates-in-tsql) this question was closed against.

Comment: @DavidG can you suggest another solutions....

Comment: Why would I want to suggest other solutions when a very simple and effective one already exists?

Comment: solutions without CTE because some old db version CTE Not working..

Comment: YES! The duplicate I linked!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136896/discussion-between-singh-kailash-and-davidg).